# Create a drop down menu using a Table Attribute in Rails Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I need to create a dropdown field(membership_code), whose values are contained on a different table called members.

## Schema

prereg
id
membership_code(string) not a foreign key
verification_code

members
id
membership_code

## Prereg Active Admin Model

```
ActiveAdmin.register Prereg do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Preregistered Users" do
      f.input :verification_code
      f.input :email
      
      #THIS LINE NEEDS TO BE CHANGED TO LIST DOWN THE MEMBERSHIP_CODE FROM MEMBERS
      # f.input :membership_code, :as => :select, :collection => Members.all()
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

To add, I was planning to have this logic wherein whenever you create a Prereg record, the selected "membership_code" would be deleted from the members.membership_code list.

How is this done in ActiveAdmin? Sorry I haven't found any good resource for DB Hooks and I'm still new to Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something as follows:

```
f.input :membership_code, as: :select, collection: Member.all.map(&:membership_code)
```

Comment: Hi @andrey this actually works! But i've encountered another problem. Since the Member Collection has a lot of records(200,000). I realised that it would be wrong to implement a dropdown option. I was thinking of using an autofill kinda of input field.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
f.input :membership_code, :as => :select, :collection => Members.select(:membership_code)
```

Thanks